# Given an associative $F$-algebra do there necessarily exist elements $a_1,a_2 \in K$ satisfying $a_1*a_2=a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, associativity

Let $F$ be a field and let $(K,*)$ be an associative $F$-algebra which, as a vector space, is finitely generated over $F$. Given an element $a\in K$, do there necessarily exist elements $a_1,a_2 \in K$ satisfying $a_1*a_2=a$?

I'm not sure how to go about this. Since we have an associative $F$-algebra we know that $v*(w*y)=(v*w)*y$ for all $v,w,y \in K$.

Comment: Well, you could take $a_1=1$ and $a_2=a$. Or, if $\lambda\in F$ is nonzero, you could take $a_1=\lambda$ and $a_2=\lambda^{-1}a$.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether your definition of "associative $F$-algebra" includes the existence of a multiplicative identity.  If it does, you can just take $a_1=1$ and $a_2=a$.  If it doesn't, such an $a_1$ and $a_2$ need not exist.  For instance, if $V$ is any vector space over $F$, you can make it a (non-unital) associative $F$-algebra by just defining $a_1*a_2=0$ for all $a_1,a_2\in V$, and then no such $a_1$ and $a_2$ exist unless $a=0$.

Comment: In this problem we don't have a multiplicative identity. How come when we define $a_1*a_2=0$ no such $a_1$ and $a_2$ exist? I don't see that.

Comment: Suppose there do exist $a_1$ and $a_2$ such that $a_1*a_2=a$.  Then $a=a_1*a_2=0$.

Comment: I don't understand what this implies. Why is this a counterexample?

Comment: If $a\in V$ is any nonzero vector, then this implies that $a\neq a_1*a_2$ for all $a_1,a_2\in V$.