# Does the "necessarily" part in the question make a difference?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, associativity

"Given an associative F-algebra do there necessarily exist elements a1.a2∈K satisfying a1∗a2=a?"

I have a question to add to the one linked below:

[Given an associative $F$-algebra do there necessarily exist elements $a_1,a_2 \in K$ satisfying $a_1*a_2=a$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428125/given-an-associative-f-algebra-do-there-necessarily-exist-elements-a-1-a-2-i/1430411#1430411)

My question:  Will there always exist a1,a2∈K satisfying a1∗a2=a? I thought for F-algebra "*" didn't necessarily have an identity element, or associativity.  I know it tells us we have an associative F-algebra, but why do those elements 'have' to exist?  There were 2 instances mentioned where they do exist, but I am wondering if they 'have to exist.'

I may just be paying too much attention to one word, but I want to make sure I understand the subject.  Thanks!

Comment: No, "necessarily exists" means "exists".

Comment: Please read the linked question and answers carefully. Your question is answered there.

Comment: Should the answer to this should be to show an example of one existing?